# Join failing in PromiseKit 3.0

Tags: swift, promisekit

I have an array of promises and I need to resolve them all and take a list of the ones that succeeded. As I understand it, I need to use `join` to do that. However, when I write:

```
let promises: [Promise<Request>] = /* ... */
let foo = join(promises)
```

I get a compile time error `Cannot invoke 'join' with argument list of type '([Promise<Request>])'`

Am I doing something wrong, or is `join` not working in Swift?

Answer (score 0):

Since this question got up-voted, I figured I should post my eventual solution.

First, calling `join` with an array was accomplished by implementing an `apply` function from http://www.drivenbycode.com/the-missing-apply-function-in-swift/

```
func apply<T, U>(fn: (T...) -> U, args: [T]) -> U {
    typealias FunctionType = [T] -> U
    return unsafeBitCast(fn, FunctionType.self)(args)
}
```

Second, it turned out that join didn't do what I needed anyway. I ended up writing my own function which I called `any`. [Collect array of successful promises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33526239/collect-array-of-successful-promises)